# Jersey (JSR311-Implementation) & Redirections

Tags: java, rest, jersey

Is there a way to redirect the user-agent in a Jersey Resource?

In Spring MVC there's the "redirect:"-syntax but I didn't find anything comparable in Jersey's `Viewable` class. The only method I found working was using `HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect()`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have to return a `Response` object containing your status code and `Location`-header. The easiest way is to use `javax.ws.rs.core.Response.temporaryRedirect(URI)`.

When using `Viewable` you might need to throw a `WebApplicationException` containing that `Response` object.

Comment: One addition. Response.temporaryRedirect(URI) returns a status of 307, which preserves the method of the initial request. Response.seeOther(URI) returns a status code of 303, which will convert a POST to a GET. So, for instance, if you POST your login credentials and redirect to the index page, you can GET the index page instead of POST'ing for it.