# URL not changing on page redirection in Jersey and MongoDB

Tags: java, jsp, redirect, jersey

My scenario is like this:
I'm building a website where I'm posting an ad regarding a topic. So, after the form filling of ad, the request goes to a REST service class as:

`http://localhost:8080/cloudproject/postadvaction?title=tution&tag=tution&description=tution+%401000+%2F+month&category=TUTOR&location=indore`

Here, the details of ad go in the database which is **MongoDB**. After all of this is done I'm redirecting to the profile page of user using **Viewable model** of jersey, where he can see all the ads posted by him. It is done as:
`return new Viewable("/profile.jsp");`
After this the response is redirected to profile page of the user.

But the problem is that, on redirecting the response to simply *profile.jsp*, the URL in the address bar has not changed to `http://localhost:8080/profile.jsp`, instead, it has remained the same as mentioned above. So, when user refreshes the page, the request of same ad post triggers and the whole process is followed again. Since, database is MongoDB, same ad is stored twice in it and same is displayed on the profile page of user with 2 identical ads.

So, how can I redirect to profile page without having the address of servlet in address bar?

**Update:** The question is related to **PRG technique & Duplicate Form Submissions** and not to just redirection.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jersey (JSR311-Implementation) & Redirections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342003/jersey-jsr311-implementation-redirections)

Comment: The question is related to Duplicate Form Submissions and PRG technique. I've edited the question to highlight the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)

> When a web form is submitted to a server through an HTTP POST request, a web user that attempts to refresh the server response in certain user agents can cause the contents of the original HTTP POST request to be resubmitted, possibly causing undesired results, such as a duplicate web purchase.
>
> To avoid this problem, many web developers use the PRG pattern[1] — instead of returning a web page directly, the POST operation returns a redirection command. The HTTP 1.1 specification introduced the HTTP 303 ("See other") response code to ensure that in this situation, the web user's browser can safely refresh the server response without causing the initial HTTP POST request to be resubmitted. However most common commercial applications in use today (new and old alike) still continue to issue HTTP 302 ("Found") responses in these situations.

With Jersey you can use

> - [`Response.seeOther(URI)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html#seeOther%28java.net.URI%29) - Create a new `ResponseBuilder` for a redirection. Used in the redirect-after-POST (aka POST/redirect/GET) pattern.

You just need to change your method signature to return a `Response` and return the built `Response`

```
return Response.seeOther(URI.create(...)).build();
```

Also stated about the `URI` parameter

> the redirection URI. If a relative URI is supplied it will be converted into an absolute URI by resolving it relative to the base URI of the application (see `UriInfo.getBaseUri()`).